# Passing fields to script

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my script, how can I read 'things' such as `autoHide: true` to set variables and whatnot on my script. I call them 'things' as I am not sure what they are called exactly thus meaning there are probably thousands of resources out there yet due to my lack of knowledge, i cannot find how to achieve this.

I wish to have multiple options such as `scrollbarWidth`, `theme` and whatnot yet not knowing how to read them on my file, I'm at a bit of a loss!

I've currently got a live demonstration [here](http://admin.rafflebananza.com/Account/demo.html) of my full working script in action.

```
(function(jQuery, undefined) {
    "use strict";
    jQuery.fn.extend({
        BananzaScroll: function() {

        // Script Functions Here

        }
    });
})(jQuery);


$( "#demo" ).BananzaScroll({
    autoHide: true  
});
```

Comment: The object will be passed as parameter to the `BananzaScroll` function: https://jsfiddle.net/80x1hLk1/. I'd suggest you read the jQuery guide on creating a plugin: https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/.

Comment: That `thing` you refer to is a `key` `:` `value` pair of an `object` (aka a hash).

Comment: Thank you @IMTheNachoMan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically just set them in the global scope.

```
<script>
    var myValue = 'abc';
</script>

(function ($) {
    console.log(myValue);
})($);
```

If you're creating something that needs lots of values, it'd be best to create an object to hold them and put just that in the global scope:

```
<script>
    var myOptions = {
        autoHide: false,
        speed: 5,
        scrollBarWidth: 10
    };
</script>
```

This keeps the global scope from getting too polluted. You'll also probably want to pseudo-namespace it to avoid collision with anything else in the global scope.

```
<script>
    var myApplicationName_myData = {};
</script>
```

If you're doing a jQuery plugin, you'll actually want to pass them as parameters to the script:

```
<script>
    $('#id').myPlugin({
        autoHide: false
    });
</script>

$.fn.myPlugin = function (options) {
    console.log(options.autoHide);
};
```

Comment: Is there any short method to check whether the option has been set to replace the default options?

Comment: If you create an object with all the defaults, and then use something like `jQuery.extend` you can apply the give options over default. E.g., `opts = $.extend(defaults, opts)`

Comment: Okay so I set up all the defaults then call this and it replaces all with whatever is set but what about `AutoHide: true/false`? Do true/false ones need an if statement?

Comment: Maybe this requires another question... I cannot work out the logic right now, in my head I'm seeing variables being lost and whatnot. Anyway, thank you for your help in obtaining these options!

Comment: Maybe you could link to a help guide if this is not a problem please?

Comment: I'm not sure of a help guide anywhere that answers your specific question. If you posted another question though, you shouldn't have any trouble getting it answered.

Answer (score 2):

Pass an argument to the definition of `BananzaScroll`, like so.

```
(function(jQuery, undefined) {
  "use strict";

  jQuery.fn.extend({
    BananzaScroll: function(opts) {
      console.log(opts); // opts contains the object you pass in
    }
  });
})(jQuery);

$('#demo').BananzaScroll({
    autoHide: true
});
```

[JSBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ralirupuge/edit?js,console)